# Using awk to svn log to get a list of file committed by a specific user

Tags: svn, awk, terminal

I found this nice little script that I've made into a bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
svn log -v -r{$1}:HEAD | awk '/^r[0-9]+ / {user=$3} /./{if (user=="'$2'") {print}}' | grep -E "^   M|^   G|^   A|^   D|^   C|^   U" | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq

$1 = 2012-10-01 //for example
$2 = George //for example
```

This script seems to work but its only printing out commits from trunk. 
When I svn log from the terminal I see all commits regardless of branch.

So far I've narrowed the problem down to awk.
We use spaces in our branch folder names. Don't sure if that could be a problem.

Is /./ in awk area the issue?

So far, I'm getting the url from the svn info and putting it in a variable.

```
theURL=$(svn info | grep -E "^(URL: )http(s)?:")
theURL=${theURL:5}
```

Perhaps I can tell awk to only print out a line where the line matches part of my url scheme?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`svn log` without path parameter uses default "." path (which must be and can be only Working Copy, in your case - linked to trunk of repo)

`svn log URL` at the same time can work with *any part of tree* for remote repository, unrelated to current setting of (some) WC.

Just add and use 3-rd parameter

Comment: actually, svn log, gives me everything branches and trunk.

Comment: so far I've narrowed it down to awk, awk '/^r[0-9]+ / {user=$3} /./{if (user=="'$2'") {print}}'. We use spaces in our branch names which I think is causing the problem.